# The Queen's Orange Curd

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, lateral-thinking

> Her yogurt is orangish.
>   The initialities form my two slices,
>   boycotting trivialities.
>   Why 'Oh!' from you comes not to you?
>   The queen's queue is immaterial;
>   its successor ends me.
>   I shewed myself in full
>   unity added with unity times.
>   What am I?

**HINT**:

(Use it only as a last resort.)

> You are me.

---

**NOTE**:

- If you have arrived at a seemingly appropriate solution,  I would suggest
  checking out the HINT to verify it.
- The accepted answer should include a thorough explanation of
  each line.
- Unless you can explain *all* the clues in *each* line *correctly*, I
  cannot say that you have *truly* figured out the answer.

Comment: Why the downvotes? The riddle is neither childish nor excruciatingly difficult.

Comment: I didn't downvote or upvote, however, it might be the too many edits you have made to the post. Perhaps, try minimizing the need for edits in general, and avoid too many minor edits. Sometimes, this might be perceived as "bumping your post to the top" to get more attention.

Comment: @MariaDeleva Thanks for the feedback, but I had to edit the riddle multiple times to make it more comprehensible.

Comment: Is there a regional/cultural aspect to this? Even knowing the correct answer, it's hard to reconcile each line to that.

Comment: No, there isn't. The riddle will turn out to be really simple, once you'll have figured it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stealing the answer from @Sid (who got it without an explanation a while ago) here's an attempt at explanation.

Her yogurt is orangish.
The initialities form my two slices,
boycotting trivialities.

> Boycott the trivialities, we get Yogurt, Orangish. From this the initials form two slices: Y,O

Why 'Oh!' from you comes not to you?

> I imagine this means "You don't parse Y,O as YOU yet? Well here's another clue"; linking in to the next couple lines.

The queen's queue is immaterial;
its successor ends me.

> The letter U follows the Q in queen. It ends the prior Yogurt Orange slices, for YOU.

Comment: Finally, someone understood my riddle! Great job! You've done it.

Comment: Your interpretation was exactly right. I'm really glad. You could add in the second line that 'Why' represents Y, and 'Oh!' O. Some people can get a little confused by the ambiguous wording.

Comment: Okay, so the orange yogurt and why Oh clue the same two letters? And what about the hint?

Comment: @Sid The 2nd and 3rd lines originally weren't there. So, I made the 4th line `Why 'Oh!'` in such a way that would hint at Y  and O. Now, merged together, they both clue at a similar concept.

Comment: @Sid I have no idea about the hint, it moves in mysterious ways

Comment: `shew` is an old-fashioned spelling of `show`, just in case you didn't know. And `unity` refers to one, in the language of mathematics, which is why, you have the `units place`. $1+1=2$.

Answer (score 7):

I can't explain everything:

But, the answer is:

> "You" (as in the word and not pointing to someone specifically)

Her yogurt is orangish.
The initialities form my two slices,
boycotting trivialities.

> Taking the initials of Yogurt and Orangish, We get YO.

Why 'Oh!' from you comes not to you?

> No idea

The queen's queue is immaterial;

> Remove the Q from QUEEN.

Its successor ends me.

> In QUEEN, U comes after Q. Interestingly, the letter at the end of "You" is U (which is also a homophone of "you").

Comment: Give a better explanation. The answer is correct, anyway. Kudos! I'm really surprised to see how fast you managed to answer it.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine The last two lines were a dead giveaway. I am still not sure about the first two lines...

Comment: Well, there's Why-Oh-You in the second line, spelling "you" and "you" is somehow contaied in yoghurt, although i have no idea why it should be orange.

Comment: @Sid, I did not originally think of the logic you gave for the last line. I merely hinted that U is a letter in the word YOU.